# Can ServiceStack.OrmLite "LoadSelect" not load IEnumerable references?

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Given the following abbreviated DTO's...

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Customer))]
    public int? CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Reference]
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }        
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Order))]
    public int? OrderID { get; set; }
    public string ProductID { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

...with the following service...

```
[Route("/orders", "GET")]
public class GetOrders : IReturn<IEnumerable<Order>>
{
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public int? Show { get; set; }
}

public class OrderService : Service
{
    public List<Order> Get(GetOrders request)
    {
        var query = Db.From<Order>()
            .OrderByDescending(q => q.ID)
            .Limit(request.Page.GetValueOrDefault(0) * request.Show.GetValueOrDefault(25), request.Show.GetValueOrDefault(25));

        return Db.LoadSelect(query);
    }
}
```

The `LoadSelect` will properly load the `Customer` reference, but it will not load the `OrderItems` reference. Is there a way to force it to? I've tried throwing in a `Join` to force it, but anything I try seems to either bomb because of the OrderBy and Limit, or it will return the entire dataset before limiting which kills performance.

Am I missing something, or is this not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I recommend using `Id` naming convention instead of `ID` when using ServiceStack libraries.

This [looks like it's a similar issue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/171) to the loading reference data with `LoadSelect` in SqlServer in a paged query that has been resolved in the latest **v4.0.34+** which is [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: Thanks so much @mythz! Great support as always. Yes, it looks like this might be the issue. I'll give it a shot. And yes, I'm using OrmLite.SqlServer with paging and orderby so it seems right up my alley. The `LoadSingleById` loaded all ref's properly so it just seemed to affect `LoadSelect`.

Comment: I got around to trying 4.0.34 from MyGet, and it's all fixed up now. Just FYI. Thanks!